# How does QueryFrame work?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv

# create a window
winname = "myWindow"
win = cv.NamedWindow(winname, cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# load video file
invideo = cv.CaptureFromFile("video.avi")

# interval between frame in ms.
fps = cv.GetCaptureProperty(invid, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
interval = int(1000.0 / fps)   

# play video
while (True):
    im = cv.QueryFrame(invideo)
    cv.ShowImage(winname, im)
    if cv.WaitKey(interval) == 27: # ASCII 27 is the ESC key
        break

del invideo
cv.DestroyWindow(winname)
```

Above is a simple python code using opencv libraray to play a video file.

The only part I don't understand is `im = cv.QueryFrame(invideo)`

According to **[opencv api](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=queryframe#QueryFrame)**, " `QueryFrame` grabs a frame from a camera or video file, decompresses it and returns it."

For my understanding, it just returns an image in `iplimage` format for one single frame, but **how does it know which frame it returns?** The only parameter `QueryFrame` need is the video capture, but there no index to tell it which frame amount the video frames I need to retrieve. What if I need to play a video starting from middle part?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `cv.GetCaptureProperty` with CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT to get the number of frames of your video.
Divide it by 2 to find the middle.
Use `QueryFrame` until you reach this value.