# OpenCV frame count wrong for interlaced videos, workaround?

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame-rate

Working with the code sample from [How does QueryFrame work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635112/how-does-queryframe-work) I noticed that the program used a lot of time to exit if it ran to the end of the video. I wanted to exit quickly on the last frame, and I verified that it's a lot quicker if I don't try to play past the end of the video, but there are some details that don't make sense to me. Here's my code:

```
import cv2

# create a window
winname = "myWindow"
win = cv2.namedWindow(winname, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# load video file
invideo = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mts")
frames = invideo.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print "frame count:", frames

# interval between frame in ms.
fps = invideo.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
interval = int(1000.0 / fps)   

# play video
while invideo.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) < frames:
    print "Showing frame number:", invideo.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    (ret, im) = invideo.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow(winname, im)
    if cv2.waitKey(interval) == 27: # ASCII 27 is the ESC key
        break

del invideo
cv2.destroyWindow(winname)
```

The only thing is that the frame count returned is 744, while the last played frame number is 371 (counting from 0, so that's 372 frames). I assume this is because the video is interlaced, and I guess I need to account for that and divide `interval` by 2 and `frames` by 2. But the question is, how do I figure out that I need to do this? There doesn't seem to be a property to check this:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

Comment: Rewritten to use cv2, it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something in between for another question and I think I should also post it here, if you are running on linux, this might be useful, so far it is working for me:

```
import subprocess
import re

inputVideo = "theFileInQuestion.mp4" # sample of interlaced video

# construct the ffmpeg command as a list of arguments
ffmpegCommand = [
    "ffmpeg", # command for ffmpeg, you need to install this with sudo apt instlal ffmpeg
    "-filter:v", "idet", # filter this specific information
    "-frames:v", "100", # test on first 100 frames
    "-an", # don't test audio
    "-f", "rawvideo", "-y", "/dev/null", # assign results to nothing
    "-i", inputVideo # on this video
]

try:
    outputBytes = subprocess.check_output(ffmpegCommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) # get the output
    outputStr = outputBytes.decode('utf-8') # decode the output
    tffLines = re.findall(r'TFF:\s+(\d+)', outputStr) # search for a pattern that is the count of top field first 
    bffLines = re.findall(r'BFF:\s+(\d+)', outputStr) # search for a pattern that is the count of  bottom field first
    totalInterlacedFrames = sum(map(int, tffLines)) + sum(map(int, bffLines)) # get total interlaced frames in the 100 checked
    if totalInterlacedFrames != 0: # check if interlaced
        print("This video is interlaced!") # YES
    else: # if not
        print("This video is not interlaced!") # NO
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error during interlacing analysis: {e}")
```

I mainly used the linux function described [here](http://www.aktau.be/2013/09/22/detecting-interlaced-video-with-ffmpeg/). I am also struggling to find any opencv prop to automatically identify interlacing.