# Discrepancy Between Frame Count Using OpenCV's cv2.VideoCapture and Manual Counting in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, avi, interlacing

I am working on a video processing project using OpenCV in Python, and I've encountered a strange issue related to counting the number of frames in a video. I am using `cv2.VideoCapture` to read the frames from a video file, but I am getting inconsistent results when counting the total number of frames.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```py
import cv2

video_path = 'MSP-IMPROV-S01A-F01-P-MF01.avi'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(f"FPS: {fps}")
total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print("Total frames using cv2.VideoCapture:", total_frames)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
frame_count = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, _ = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frame_count += 1
cap.release()
print("Manually counted frames:", frame_count)
```

The output I'm getting is as follows:

```
FPS: 59.94005994005994
Total frames using cv2.VideoCapture: 1187
Manually counted frames: 594
```

Initially, I was puzzled by the discrepancy in the frame counts. However, upon closer inspection of the output frames, I noticed that the frames are being halved, and it seems OpenCV is skipping frames uniformly with a stride of one (i.e., one every two frames).

Could this be an issue with how OpenCV is reading the video file? Here are some additional considerations:

The video file format is AVI. Could this format be influencing how OpenCV reads the frames?
Is this a known behavior or limitation in OpenCV's frame reading mechanism?
Are there specific settings or parameters in cv2.VideoCapture that I need to adjust to avoid skipping frames?
I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to ensure that OpenCV reads every frame of the video without skipping.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try again with `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, True)`. Maybe the frames are interlaced, the manually counting is almost exactly half as much.

Comment: Maybe you can share the video using Google Drive, Dropbox, Github or somesuch so other folks can analyse it?

Comment: Also would be helpful to upload the file so we can have access to it, try google drive and then posting a link

Comment: Which VideoIO backend are you using? FFMPEG? Something else?

Comment: @DanMašek To be honest, I'm not entirely certain which backend OpenCV is using in my setup. I am simply using cv2.VideoCapture to read the video file.

Comment: @TinoD Unfortunately, I cannot share the video file due to academic copyright restrictions as it's part of a dataset obtained from a university. I understand this limits the extent to which others can directly assist, but I appreciate the offer to help.

Comment: Additional observations that might be relevant:
The original framerate of the video is 60fps, but OpenCV seems to be reading only half of them. This is consistent across different videos in this dataset.
Another dataset with AVI videos at 30fps does not exhibit this issue, suggesting that the problem may be specific to higher frame rates or this particular dataset's encoding.

Comment: @PrashantKhatri so set the fps of the VideoCapture at 60 fps.

Comment: what's the result of `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` for all your videos? If it is 30 for all (which is the default) then there is your problem.

Comment: Forget my last comment, opencv correctly identifies fps

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem with an interlaced video. Again, in case your video is interlaced. Can you check if it is?

Comment: if you can use ffmpeg, then check interlacing of the video by using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895036/16815358

Comment: in my experience, that's due to the source material being interlaced. haven't seen this clean 2:1 ratio in any other situation. also, the "FRAME_COUNT" property isn't all that accurate. file a bug against opencv (check if any exists already! and reproduce on latest release), hope that someone looks into it

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer might be useful in any case. Though I would be surprised if your video would not be interlaced, since this clear twice amount of frames is a very big indicator.

I created a function to test if the video is interlaced, it is based on ffmpeg, so you would have to get it with `sudo apt install ffmpeg`.

After that, I wrote this function in python to return `True`, `False`, or an error message in case anything goes wrong:

```
def testInterlacing(inputVideo):
    import subprocess
    import re
    # construct the ffmpeg command as a list of arguments
    ffmpegCommand = [
        "ffmpeg", # command for ffmpeg, you need to install this with sudo apt instlal ffmpeg
        "-filter:v", "idet", # filter this specific information
        "-frames:v", "100", # test on first 100 frames
        "-an", # don't test audio
        "-f", "rawvideo", "-y", "/dev/null", # assign results to nothing
        "-i", inputVideo # on this video
    ]
    try:
        outputBytes = subprocess.check_output(ffmpegCommand, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) # get the output
        outputStr = outputBytes.decode('utf-8') # decode the output
        tffLines = re.findall(r'TFF:\s+(\d+)', outputStr) # search for a pattern that is the count of top field first 
        bffLines = re.findall(r'BFF:\s+(\d+)', outputStr) # search for a pattern that is the count of  bottom field first
        totalInterlacedFrames = sum(map(int, tffLines)) + sum(map(int, bffLines)) # get total interlaced frames in the 100 checked
        if totalInterlacedFrames != 0: # check if interlaced
            return True # YES
        else: # if not
            return False # NO
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return e
```

After this, you can use this function in your main, to dictate how the counting should work:

```
import cv2
inputVideoInterlaced = "letterman.mp4" # sample of interlaced video
inputVideoNotInterlaced = "countdown.mp4" # sample of nt interlaced video
inputVideo = inputVideoInterlaced # choose which file

if testInterlacing(inputVideo):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputVideo)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print(f"FPS: {fps}")
    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print("Total frames using cv2.VideoCapture:", total_frames//2) # divide by 2!
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputVideo)
    frame_count = 0
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, _ = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame_count += 1
    cap.release()
    print("Manually counted frames:", frame_count)
    
elif not(testInterlacing(inputVideo)):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputVideo)
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print(f"FPS: {fps}")
    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print("Total frames using cv2.VideoCapture:", total_frames)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputVideo)
    frame_count = 0
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, _ = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame_count += 1
    cap.release()
    print("Manually counted frames:", frame_count)
    
else:
    e = testInterlacing(inputVideo)
    print("Error while checking if video is interlaced:\n"+e)
```

I copy pasted your code into the answer with only the small adjustment of dividing the number of cv2 frames by 2 when interlaced is detected.

Hope this helps you further.